# how to remove the duplicated recordes java jsp LinkedHashSet ArrayList

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, hashset, linkedhashset

the ObjectToReturn model consists many element such as: txtfile, time, writer, txtcontent.....
By processing the OjectToReturn, I can extract the whole element into seprate ArrayList such as "displayTXTfileList", "displayTXTContentList".....

in servlet:

```
  request.setAttribute("ObjectToReturn",ObjectToReturn);

 request.setAttribute("displayTXTfileList",displayTXTfileList); 
 request.setAttribute("displayTXTContentList",displayTXTContentList);
```

in JSP:

```
 <table  border="1" >
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th>txt name</th>
    <th>txt content</th>

  </tr>
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.ObjectToReturn}" var="result">
<tr><td><c:out value="${result.txtfile}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${result.txtcontent}"></c:out></td></tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
```

as the record in the Arraylist (ObjectToReturn) is duplicated. 
as u can see from the picture.

How to remove the duplicated rows???
[image]

I do not know how to use  LinkedHashSet to get the unique record.

Comment: Instead of ArrayList use LinkedHashSet.
LinkedHashSet displayTXTfileList = new LinkedHashSet();
LinkedHashSet displayTXTContentList = new LinkedHashSet();

Comment: How did you frame ObjectToReturn object ?